# Load app_config.yml in capistrano deploy.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Using Rails 3.2 and Capistrano 2. I have an `app_config.yml` which I load to the app this way:

```
# config/app_config.yml
global: &GLOBAL
  sitename: Shop

# config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__))[Rails.env]

# call using this method
<%= APP_CONFIG["sitename"] %>
```

I want to load the same `app_config.yml` in my deployment scripts in Capistrano, so that I don't have to re-set the variables again:

```
# config/deploy.rb
require "bundler/capistrano"

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__))[Rails.env]

set :stages, %w(production staging)
```

And I hope to access the variable using this way too: `APP_CONFIG["sitename"]`, but as I run the deployment script, I get this error:

```
./config/deploy.rb:4:in `load': uninitialized constant Capistrano::Configuration::Rails
(NameError) # points to the APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file... line
```

How can I load the `app_config.yml` file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano does not require any rails code.

That's why calling `APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__))[Rails.env]` raises the exception.

You need to replace the `Rails.env` with something else that is used in your capistrano deployment. That might be the stage or just `"production"` depending on your setup.

You could do something like this in `config/deploy.rb`:

```rb
app_config = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__), aliases: true)[fetch(:stage).to_s]

set :application, app_config['app_name']
```

The `fetch(:stage)` is where we're getting the stage (`production`, `development`, etc), and `.to_s` was necessary for me to be able to get it to load the keys correctly.

(The `aliases: true` is only needed if you're using YAML aliases, a.k.a. little variable-like reusable snippets in your YAML file, which I do to keep it cleaner and less duplicated.)